# Logs not showing in Google Cloud Platform Stackdriver when using new Google Cloud logging jar

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I followed the documentation on  [Java logging libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java), the `QuickstartSample.java` is a simple API call to log data to Stackdriver.

```
public class QuickstartSample {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    // Instantiates a client
    Logging logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // The name of the log to write to
    String logName = "test-log";

    // The data to write to the log
    String text = "Hello, world!";

    LogEntry entry = LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of(text))
            .setSeverity(Severity.ERROR)
            .setLogName(logName)
            .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build())
            .build();

            logging.write(Collections.singleton(entry));

     System.out.printf("Logged: %s%n", text);

  }
}
```

No log entry is showing when I use `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:1.87.0` version.

It works correctly with the older version `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:1.2.1`

Windows 7 64bit

OpenJDK 8 64bit

Gradle version 3.0 
(Also with maven 3.6.1 with same result)

There is no error in console when I run the code, complete program is executed in both the cases but logs are shipped to Stackdriver only when using 1.2.1 version.

I need to integrate Stackdriver with my project and I want to use the newer version. Does anyone know a possible cause for this?

Comment: Can you share to us which builder you are using e.g. Gradle, Also had you tried any of the troubleshoot tools in order to know where exactly the log information is getting stocked [1]. 

I recommend to share any detail you can about how you are calling. 

NOTE com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging last version is 1.88.0

Take a look on this github document (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-logging)

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/troubleshooting

Comment: I have added the details in the question. I tried 1.88.0 version but same result as 1.87.0. My project key is in place, it is working properly with old jar. I have not used any debugging tools, do you have any suggestion regarding tools that could help me here?

Comment: Hi Divya, did you find any solution on this, I'm also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and I got it to work in two ways:

1. By running synchronous calls by setting the write synchronicity to sync:

```
// Writes the log entry synchronously
logging.setWriteSynchronicity(Synchronicity.SYNC);
logging.write(Collections.singleton(entry));
```

2. By flushing asynchronous calls:

```
// Writes the log entry asynchronously
logging.write(Collections.singleton(entry));
logging.flush();
```

I'm using `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:1.101.2`